# C# / LINQ Error: A local variable named 'mbr' is already defined in this scope

Tags: c#, linq, switch-statement, case-statement

Without having to put braces {} on each case and adding the code to each case. Is there an easier way around doing that? Currently I get an error doing the way I have below and am trying to avoid using braces and adding the same code to each case. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
private int GetMemberInfoByID(string strMemberID, int intAVersion)
        {
            try
            {

                switch (intAVersion)
                {
                    case (int)A_Version.A6:
                        dbA6ReplDataContext mbr = new dbA6ReplDataContext();
                        break;
                    case (int)A_Version.A7:
                        dbA7ReplDataContext mbr = new dbA7ReplDataContext();
                        break;
                }

                var member = (
                       from m in mbr.MEMBERs
                       join ma in mbr.ADDRESSes on "S " + m.CONTRACT_NBR equals ma.ADDR_WHO
                       where m.MEMBER_NBR == strMemberID
                          && (ma.VOID[0] != 'V'
                       select ma.YMDEND).ToList();

                if (member == null || member.Count == 0)
                    return Int32.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
                else
                    return member.Max();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cError err = new cError();
                err.ErrorMessage(ex);
                err = null;

                return Int32.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: If they don't have a base class you'll have to duplicate the code

Comment: @DarrenYoung I thought the same thing till I realized the types are different in each block.

Comment: Yep, sorry. My bad!

Comment: Hence the issue I've been having. I originally had the same thought @DarrenYoung but like mentioned, the types are different which causes an issue doing that way.

Comment: Why not just use brackets? I don't see why it would be a problem. I think that is the best solution here instead of some trickery code.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen care to elaborate on your thought? That is a pretty generic statement.

Comment: Really the only solution (if you dont want to scope it) would be to have both the dbA6ReplDataContext and dbA7ReplDataContext derive from some common base class. Then you could declare the mbr variable of the base class type before the switch

Comment: @Tvde1 by using braces that means I have to repeat the same code in each case, I am trying to avoid being repetitive.

Comment: Base class or interface would be cleanest. `dynamic` may work, but you at least won't have intellisense or compile time validation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the `dbA6ReplDataContext` & `dbA7ReplDataContext` classes are very similar. If that is the case, the best way to do this would be to create a common interface for the two of them & declare your variable as that type.

```
IReplDataContext mbr = null;
switch (intAVersion)
{
    case (int)A_Version.A6:
        mbr = new dbA6ReplDataContext();
        break;
    case (int)A_Version.A7:
        mbr = new dbA7ReplDataContext();
        break;
}
```

Using the common interface (`IReplDataContext` in the example) would allow you to continue to use the similarities between the two types while still providing type safety.

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that 'mbr' as it is declared in the question is in a different scope then where it is being consumed. This solution also fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic` typing to avoid duplicating code at the cost of losing compile-time checks:

```
dynamic mbr = null;
switch (intAVersion)
{
    case (int)A_Version.A6:
        mbr = new dbA6ReplDataContext();
        break;
    case (int)A_Version.A7:
        mbr = new dbA7ReplDataContext();
        break;
}
```

Up to you to add whatever validation you want, such as a `null` check in case `intAVersion` is invalid.